# How to "transpose" Objects in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects, transpose

Is there a way to nicely convert from an object:

```
Key_1 : {Head_1 : "val_11", Head_2 : "val_21", Head_3 : "val_31"}
Key_2 : {Head_1 : "val_12", Head_2 : "val_22", Head_3 : "val_32"}
Key_3 : {Head_1 : "val_13", Head_2 : "val_23", Head_3 : "val_33"}
```

to:

```
Head_1 : {Key_1 : "val_11", Key_2 : "val_12", Key_3: "val_13"}
Head_2 : {Key_1 : "val_21", Key_2 : "val_22", Key_3: "val_23"}
Head_3 : {Key_1 : "val_31", Key_2 : "val_32", Key_3: "val_33"}
```

In TypeScript?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "for..of" and "Object.entries" like below to transpose

BTW, it's always better to write your approach/what have you tried in OP so that fellow users see where you are heading towards

```js
var obj = {
  Key_1 : {Head_1 : "val_11", Head_2 : "val_21", Head_3 : "val_31"},
  Key_2 : {Head_1 : "val_12", Head_2 : "val_22", Head_3 : "val_32"},
  Key_3 : {Head_1 : "val_13", Head_2 : "val_23", Head_3 : "val_33"}
}

function transpose(obj) {
  let newObj = {}
  for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    for(let [k, v] of Object.entries(value)) { 
       newObj[k] = newObj[k] || {}
       newObj[k][key] = v
    }
  }
  return newObj
}

console.log(transpose(obj))
```

Comment: Why do you mix `for … of` with `forEach` style loops? That looks horrible. Use a proper `for … of` loop and don't abuse the comma operator.

Comment: Done @Bergi. I see your point of consistency in using `for..of`... I see it's horrible for you... just want to understand 'don't abuse the comma operator'.. Where an how did I abuse that, just for my understanding.

Comment: @NitishNarang Thanks for the edit. The problem I had with the comma operator was that `([k, v]) => 
        ( newObj[k] = newObj[k] || {}
          , newObj[k][key] = v
        )` could have been written much cleaner (and just as short) as `([k, v]) => 
        { newObj[k] = newObj[k] || {}
          ; newObj[k][key] = v
        }`

Comment: Oh!! I get that. Thank you for pointing.. It's just my way of going comma first approach while coding... But will make sure code looks cleaner and easy to understand as well. :)

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are great but I don't see anything that deals with the type system specific to TypeScript.  The following type definitions and signature should allow the compiler to understand the type of the transposed object  (assuming TS2.8+):

```
type AllKeys<T> = T extends any ? keyof T : never;
type RelevantKeys<T, K extends keyof T[keyof T]> = {
    [L in keyof T]: K extends keyof T[L] ? L : never
}[keyof T];

type Transpose<T> = {
    [K in AllKeys<T[keyof T]>]: {
        [L in RelevantKeys<T, K>]: T[L][K]
    }
};    

function transpose<T extends object & Record<keyof T, object>>(t: T): Transpose<T>;
// one possible implementation, use your favorite from above
function transpose(t: { [k: string]: { [l: string]: any } }) {
    const ret = {} as { [l: string]: { [k: string]: any } };
    Object.keys(t).forEach(k =>
        Object.keys(t[k]).forEach(l => {
            if (!(l in ret)) ret[l] = {};
            ret[l][k] = t[k][l];
        })
    );
    return ret;
}
```

Observe the types:

```
var obj = {
  Key_1: { Head_1: "val_11", Head_2: "val_21", Head_3: "val_31" },
  Key_2: { Head_1: "val_12", Head_2: "val_22", Head_3: "val_32" },
  Key_3: { Head_1: "val_13", Head_2: "val_23", Head_3: "val_33" }
}
const transposed = transpose(obj);

// the following are compile-time IntelliSense and/or error messages
transposed.Head_1; // {Key_1: string, Key_2: string, Key_3: string};
transposed.Haed_2; // error, property Haed2 does not exist
transposed.Head_3.Key_2; // string

const x = { a: { b: 1, c: true }, d: { e: "hey", f: undefined } };
const y = transpose(x);
y.e.d; // string
y.e.a; // error, property 'a' does not exist on {d: string}
y.b.a; // number
y.b.d; // error, property 'd' does not exist on {a: number}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use `Array.prototype.reduce`:

```js
const input = {
  Key_1: {Head_1: 'val_11', Head_2: 'val_21', Head_3: 'val_31'},
  Key_2: {Head_1: 'val_12', Head_2: 'val_22', Head_3: 'val_32'},
  Key_3: {Head_1: 'val_13', Head_2: 'val_23', Head_3: 'val_33'},
};

const output = Object.entries(input).reduce((acc, [key, keyVal]) => {
  Object.entries(keyVal).forEach(([head, headVal]) => {
    acc[head] = acc[head] || {};
    acc[head][key] = headVal;
  });
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(output);
```

Don't forget to transpile and add polyfills if required for compatibility.